# Attempt to Present whose view not in window hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having the following issue when presenting the `UITableViewController`.

`List[12426:444700] Warning: Attempt to present <UserTableViewController: 0x7fe4ba5d8e50> on <UserViewController: 0x7fe4ba5b6db0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Here's the part of my code

```
@implementation UserTableViewController
@synthesize users;
- (void)viewDidLoad {


// UserTableViewController
//  Create Fetch Request in viewDidLoad
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
//Create NSManagedObjectContext instance

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription  *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];
//setting users with array of fetched objects
[self setUsers:array];
NSLog(@"firstName is %@",array);
//[self presentViewController:UserTableViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Really appreciate help.

Comment: Nothing you posted is the problem because you aren't doing anything with a view or view controller.

Comment: You should show where and how are you presenting this controller

Comment: I'll be able to give more advice if you post the code around where you do the `presentViewController` from `UserViewController` and if you describe how UserViewController is added to the view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to present (`[self presentViewController:animated:completion:]`) `UserTableViewController` from within your `UserViewController` when your `UserViewController` instance is not part of the window hierarchy, e.g. on the navigation stack (has been pushed or presented itself).